# Is it haughty to wear a frock when one is undeserving?

Tags: rabbis, middos-character-traits

Many Rabbis wear a long Black Coat called a frock as rabbinic garb. Since it is a rabbinical garb is it permitted for someone who is not a rabbi to wear it? is it haughty to do so?

Rabbis wear black frocks [here](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjudaism.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F53405%2Fwhy-do-some-rabbis-wear-a-black-frock-coat&ei=RSuMVYS4LKSz7AakyIKACg&usg=AFQjCNFVa4D41JVAl4OIuE_YCRpVQH_-Jg&sig2=2XFw47NorjWrF4zxbVAcPA&bvm=bv.96782255,d.ZGU) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frock_coat)

Comment: Funny you asked this, as I just saw a fellow who is not a Rabbi and he recently put one on.

Comment: im confused why i need to argue that rabbis, whether charedi, zionist, across the board wear frocks.

Comment: You just need to support any claim as best you can. If it's not controversial, it should be very easy to support. The rabbi at my local shul, for instance, does not wear a frock.

Comment: so he chose not to (assuming he is worthy, i have no idea what your religious affiliation is), but please dont argue with me that it is a rabbinical thing, it is a rabbinacal thing to give a sermon, but not all rabbis do. but dont tell me a sermon isnt rabbinical.

Comment: I'm making a counter-argument. Why do you think a frock is specifically Rabbinical garb to the point that non-Rabbi should be prohibited from wearing it? Some Hassidic rabbis wear shtreimelach, white socks and long black robes. Many Hassidim who are not rabbis do likewise. I'm not a Hassid, but am I prohibited from dressing like one if I wish?

Comment: @GershonGold did anybody say anything to him? or did he explain why he started?

Comment: @DanF: Although the Chassidic Rabbis wear shtreimelach, white socks and long black robes, the Rabbi's often wear a felt edging on the Beketche which differentiates them from the Chasid.

Comment: @GershonGold I never knew that. You must be around Hassidm a lot. *L'havdil*, it sounds like the "stripes" the college dean wears on his robe during graduation ceremony ;-)

Comment: Mokay, most married Lubavitchers (Chabadniks) wear a black frock coat (with four buttons, buttoned right over left) on Shabbat, Yom Tov, and other important occasions. Not all married chassidei Chabad have semicha, so obviously they do not view it as haughtiness.

Comment: @MOKAY I'm just asking you to support your claims. Not that complicated.

Comment: My Rabbi in Yeshiva used to tell us the story of a certain Talmid Chacham from Chicago who moved to Eretz Yisrael. When he moved, he would wear a short (i.e. normal) jacket. Someone once asked him why he doesn't wear a longer coat, i.e. frack. (Frock is a piece of clothing for females.) He replied that we know that a talmid chacham needs to be clearly different in the way he dresses. He wanted to make sure he didn't look like all of the am-haaratzim around...

Answer (score 2):

There are many communities in which the custom is to start wearing this either from bar mitzvah or from being married. That being the case in such a community it would have nothing to do with being a rabbi. If one were to attach to it a special significance of only being for Rabbis as a specific custom perhaps you could make that case but I see no advantage in doing so

Comment: In the Litvisch welt, it is customary for roshei yeshiva to wear frock coats (Yiddish: kapote).

Comment: Only the rosh yeshiva? Why?

Comment: It's a thing in some yeshivot. FWIW, the mesader kiddushin at my cousin's (Modern) Orthodox wedding in Israel over the summer wore typical r"y garb (kapote and Homburg hat) as he (R' Landau) is (or was) the head of the kiddushin bureau in the Tel Aviv rabbanut. A further aside, I've heard that when R' Pam didn't wear a frock coat on becoming an r"y at Torah Vodaas, it was somewhat controversial.

Comment: Interesting side note there are many who regularly wear a kappota on shabbos/yontiff who will wear a coat over top of it when walking outside so as not to show it off

Comment: @Noach MiFrankfurt ,Rav Dovid Feinstein does not wear a frock as well

Answer (score 1):

The Sefer Shulchan Aruch Hamiddot says that since a frock traditionally (especially in Litvish - Lithuanian) circles is a special Rabbinic garb. If someone who is not qualified, due to lack of scholarship or lack of position of authority chooses to wear one is exhibiting the behavior of Gaava - haughtiness.